# Do high-end graphics cards yield better 2D editing performance than "mid-range" cards?

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, desktop-computer, photos

I'm getting ready to buy/build a desktop PC explicitly for the purpose of editing high-resolution RAW photos (20-30 MB each). I'm on a limited budget so I'd like to prioritize which specific attributes I absolutely need to focus on and which ones I can "skimp" on.

I'm conflicted on the topic of high-end video cards.  Do they yield better 2-D performance than mid-range cards?  Would it be worth spending more for a video card and compromising on, say, RAM? Or a lower CPU speed?

Comment: What software do you use? You might find that it's the CPU/RAM combo that makes a different on older software.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2D tests out there on hardware tests sites. Through a culmination of the data they provide and my own experience the 2D speeds have gone to heck even (back some time ago). In the fight for the almighty 3D, which many 2d programs are employing for speed anyway. I had a old matrox card that could barely even play any game, some of the 2d tests (of many) showed it to be 2-3times faster than the primo 3D card I was changing to at the time.

If i remember right there are cards out there that specialise in 2D still, but they are not consumer type.

Not much of that has changed, before buying this latests grafics card, I spent a few extra hours trying to discover any 2D reasoning behind purchacing AMD over NVIDIA or any specific card. There was nothing special that stood out about any of the consumer cards for the 2D speeds (via 2d speed tests).

The implemetation of new methods has Always taken some time from the chip manufactures putting in great new features and co-processing,  like intels SSE 1-4 and 3D now , mmx , avx. GPU cross utalisation,  the OS implementing the features and diverging the compatability , the programmers implementing the features, the Finished program making it to the users and it failing :-) a bit until all the new bugs are worked out.

In the links below I will not try to explain, being just a user, but it follows trend, and you can see what is up with the OS side.
The layers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417756(v=vs.85).aspx

Warp? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx#introduction

Software, I also work with lots of pictures at times doing minor stuff, and there is more simple software out there other than photo programs that have done my simple processing up to 100 times faster, without catch words and cute phrases and extensive feature.  The selection of software for the specific job could be very important, even after much of this stuff is implemented.

Many Photo programs "filters" (effects) and 3rd party filters can be set to do the work they do in the GPU, which can make them many times faster. If you are going to be using these specific filters, the GPU speed could become very important. It is usually the very slow filters that they are more likley to push into gpu rendering. Most of that type of filter is usually "art" creation and creative manipulation, not portrait photograper, or airbrusher , or photo cleanup type of work.

Conclusion:  You have a lot of Data in uncompressed files, concentrate on it first, get your Ram up to keep out of paging and scratch, get your storage data up to speed. Check out what the programs you use are going to do to utalise any new capabilites and features. Get a Ok grafics card, not a bad one, and not a $1500 one , unless it is specific to not only the job your doing but the software your doing it in. Have a Backup.   Move foreward from there, good luck.